# Create Clob object from string and list and store into oracle timesten database

Tags: java, clob, timesten

I have string and listArray which I want to store into Oracle Timesten table in columnType Clob.
So First I'm tring to convert String and list into Clob object.
But while creating CLOB object , I'm getting errors.

Please suggest.

````
**Create Clob Object**
//Create RecordObject ro and then write into Clob object . Copy method used to get field list.
public RecordObject convertToRecordObject(EventRecord er) throws SQLException, IOException {
    Clob clob = null;
    RecordObject ro = new RecordObject(er.getOriginalFilename().toString(), new ArrayList<RecordField>());
    copy(er, ro.getFieldsList());
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(clob.setAsciiStream(0));
    out.writeObject(ro);
    logger.info("Record Object :: " + ro.getFieldsList());
    return ro;
    }


**Store Clob Object to DB**

//Connected to Timesten DB , Prepared Statement and then 

psmt.setString(1, key);
psmt.setClob(1, key);
psmt.executeUpdate();


**RecordObject.java**
//Record Object having string and no. of fields in list
public class RecordObject implements Serializable {
    private String file_name;
    private List<RecordField> fieldsList;
    public RecordObject(String file_name, List<RecordField> fieldsList) {
        this.file_name = file_name;
        this.fieldsList = fieldsList;
    }
    RecordObject() {}
    public List<RecordField> getFieldsList() {
        return fieldsList;
    }

    public void setFieldsList(List<RecordField> fieldsList) {
        this.fieldsList = fieldsList;
    }
    public String getFile_name() {
        return file_name;
    }

    public void setFile_name(String file_name) {
        this.file_name = file_name;
    }
}```
````

Comment: [*But while creating CLOB object , I'm getting errors.*](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/17-errors)
Also, not *clob.setAsciiStream* but `clob.setBinaryStream`. Serialization produces binary data. 'RecordField' will have to be `Serializable`

Comment: Thanks for help. Along with "setBinaryStream" I have added below line which solved my problem.
Blob blob = DBManager.getConnection().createBlob();